# Проблема с простым симулятором воды

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу простой симулятор воды на клеточном автомате.

Но вода течет корректно только по 2м направлениям - вниз и влево. Также с каждой итерацией теряется часть массы воды.

Не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

mapw=16
maph=16
air=0
ground=1
water=2

blocks=[]
mass=[]
newmass=[]

MaxMass = 1.0
MaxCompress = 0.02
MinMass = 0.0001
MaxSpeed = 1.0;
MinFlow = 0.01;

for x in range(maph+2):
    a=[]
    for y in range(mapw+2):
        a.append(0)
    blocks.append(a)

for x in range(maph+2):
    a=[]
    for y in range(mapw+2):
        a.append(0.0)
    mass.append(a)
    
for x in range(maph+2):
    a=[]
    for y in range(mapw+2):
        a.append(0.0)
    newmass.append(a)

def bounds(am, low, high):
    if am<=low:
        return low
    elif am>=high:
        return high
    else:
        return am

def stableBottom(totalmass):
    if totalmass<=1.0:
        return totalmass
    elif totalmass<(2.0*MaxMass+MaxCompress):
        return(MaxMass*MaxMass+totalmass*MaxCompress)/(MaxMass+MaxCompress)
    else:
        return(totalmass+MaxCompress)/2.0

def SimWater():
    sm=0
    for x in range(1,mapw+1):
        for y in range(1,maph+1):
            
            if blocks[x][y] == ground:
                continue
            
            flow=0
            remainingmass=mass[x][y]
            newmass[x][y]=mass[x][y]
            
            if remainingmass<=0.0:
                continue
            
            #блок под
            if blocks[x][y-1]!=ground:
                flow=stableBottom(remainingmass+mass[x][y-1])-mass[x][y-1]
                flow=bounds(flow, 0, min(MaxSpeed,remainingmass))
                if flow>2*MinFlow:
                    flow*=0.5
                newmass[x][y]-=flow
                newmass[x][y-1]+=flow
                remainingmass-=flow
                
            if remainingmass<=0.0:
                continue
            
            #блок слева
            if blocks[x-1][y]!=ground:
                flow=(remainingmass-mass[x-1][y])/4
                flow=bounds(flow, 0, min(MaxSpeed,remainingmass))
                if flow>2*MinFlow:
                    flow*=0.5
                newmass[x][y]-=flow
                newmass[x-1][y]+=flow
                remainingmass-=flow               
                
            if remainingmass<=0.0:
                continue
            
            #блок справа
            if blocks[x+1][y]!=ground:
                flow=(remainingmass+flow-mass[x+1][y])/4
                flow=bounds(flow, 0, min(MaxSpeed,remainingmass))
                if flow>2*MinFlow:
                    flow*=0.5
                newmass[x][y]-=flow
                newmass[x+1][y]+=flow
                remainingmass-=flow               
                
            if remainingmass<=0.0:
                continue
            
            #блок над
            if blocks[x][y+1]!=ground:
                flow=remainingmass-stableBottom(remainingmass+mass[x][y+1])
                flow=bounds(flow, 0, min(MaxSpeed,remainingmass))
                if flow>2*MinFlow:
                    flow*=0.5
                newmass[x][y]-=flow
                newmass[x][y+1]+=flow
                remainingmass-=flow
                
            if remainingmass<=0.0:
                continue
                            
    for x in range(mapw+2):
        for y in range(maph+2):
            mass[x][y]=newmass[x][y]
            
    for x in range(1,mapw+1):
        for y in range(1,maph+1):
            if blocks[x][y]==ground:
                continue
            elif mass[x][y]>MinMass:
                blocks[x][y]=water
            else:
                blocks[x][y]=air
                mass[x][y]=0.0
                
    for x in range(mapw+2):
        mass[x][0]=0
        mass[x][maph+1]=0
        
    for y in range(1,maph+1):
        mass[0][y]=0
        mass[mapw+1][y]=0
        
    for x in range(mapw+2):
        for y in range(maph+2):
            sm+=mass[x][y]
        
    print("SM: "+str(sm))

blocks[3][5]=1 
blocks[3][6]=1
blocks[3][7]=1  
blocks[3][8]=1
blocks[3][9]=1
blocks[4][4]=1        
blocks[5][3]=1
blocks[6][3]=1
blocks[7][4]=1
blocks[8][5]=1
blocks[9][5]=1
blocks[9][6]=1
blocks[9][7]=1
blocks[9][8]=1
blocks[9][9]=1
blocks[9][10]=1
blocks[9][11]=1
blocks[10][11]=1
blocks[11][11]=1
blocks[11][12]=1
blocks[11][13]=1
blocks[5][12]=2
mass[5][12]=2
plt.matshow(np.rot90(blocks), cmap="RdYlBu")
for i in range(40):
    SimWater()
    plt.matshow(np.rot90(blocks), cmap="RdYlBu")

tm=0

for x in range(mapw+2):
        for y in range(maph+2):
            if mass[x][y]>0:
                tm+=mass[x][y]

print("SM: "+str(tm))
```